# How to filter a white noise or random noise in Matlab Simulink?

Tags: matlab, filters, noise

I am working on a sun-synchronous satellite Simulink model wich determines its attitude from a Sun sensor and a star sensor whom measure the sun and star direction in the satellite body reference frame. I have to introduce measure errors on both sensors using a "white noise" Simulink block, but I prefer to generate the noise through a Matlab function block using the function "rand" (or shoul'd I use the "randn" function?).

My issue is that I have to filter the noises on the measurements before sending them to a block who compute the attitude quaternion error to feed it to a PID controller blockset which commands a Reaction Wheels Assembly. Without noise the satellite flies smoothly.

I have tried some solution such as lowpass filter, Butterworth filter, mean on peaks and downs, but nothing seems to work properly.

I cannot figure out, for example, which should be the cut off frequency to set up on a lowpass filter ( I cannot figure out if the lowpass filter is the correct choice for such a problem, too).

Comment: You should use randn for gaussian n, not randn

Second of all, you do realize your whole PID control loop is a low-pass filter, right?

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to have a deeper understanding of you satellite's dynamics. 
What I mean is that by observing your attitude quaternion error variation DSP ( or using the motion mathematical model), you may be able to choose a convenient filtering type/tuning to get rid of most possible white noise.

Comment: I could place a lowpass fiilter befor the derivative control of the PID, but I am not able to select a cut-off frequency. Introducing the nise in the sensors measures "make to explode" the simulation rsulting in an uncontrollabe satellite. I would like to know how to get rid of the noise in the measures or how to render unsensitive the PID control to the noise.

Comment: I understand your concerns, My point was that tuning is different from an extreme case where the satellite is rapidly spinning around itself or a more smooth satellite motion case. In addition, the white noise will be covering all your useful signal's frequency band. Thus, you may not be to get rid of it with a lowpass filter. Have you considered averaging filtering ? This will help reduce the noise level and may solve the problem. Anyway, you may want to check this source about filtering options in a control system https://controlguru.com/using-signal-filters-in-our-pid-loop/

Comment: Here is a reseach gate discussion about how to white noise filtering methods depending on the tradeoff: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_white_noise_can_be_eliminated_efficiently .

Comment: Thank you.My satellite is spinning on the pitch axis once per orbit, so it is a slow spinning satellite on one axis , and no spinning on the other axes. I will check your proposal. Thank you so much! Em